# Display google maps in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to php and I'm trying to display a google maps location with dynamic coordinates. Here's the code where I do the queries:

```
$longitudine="select longitudine from sedi, stati, tappe, spedizioni where $idSpedizione=tappe.spedizione and tappe.stato=idStato and sedi.citta=tappe.luogoInizio group by data desc limit 1;";
$longi=$conn->query($longitudine);
$longg=mysqli_fetch_array ($longi);

$latitudine="select latitudine from sedi, stati, tappe, spedizioni where $idSpedizione=tappe.spedizione and tappe.stato=idStato and sedi.citta=tappe.luogoInizio group by data desc limit 1;";
$lati=$conn->query($latitudine);
$lat=mysqli_fetch_array ($lati);
```

And here is the code:

```
<style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

 <div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {

    var uluru = { lat: 47.37, lng: 9.200000 };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: uluru,
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map,
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
 ></script>
```

Basically I want to set the coordinates with the values of the queries, but when I try it doesn't show me the map. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your exact issue? The map code doesn't make use of the query code. And that query code seems invalid; why do you use a variable `$idSpedizione` as a column name?

Comment: sorry $idSpedizione is a variable that i pass using the session, but i''d like to sobstitute the lat and lng with the results of the queries

Comment: Well, then it would be a good time to write some code that does that. But you haven't given enough context for us to even send you in the right direction. Are you looking to obtain this on page load or some other event? When/how are those queries triggered? How are those two pieces of code related? And you still haven't answered why you use that variable (which I assume holds a *value*, judging by its name) as a *column name*. I sincerely doubt you need to join on a different column based on some parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your both php and script code as above are on the **same page**, you can add php variables to your script's `uluru` variable  as:

```
var uluru = { lat: <?php echo floatval($lat["latitudine"]) ?>, lng: <?php echo floatval($longg["longitudine"]) ?> };
```

Please note its not a standard way to add php variables to your script code like that but it may work on your code. You can try.

---

P.S: Please don't reveal your API key as you did in your question. Please edit and change it to `MY_API_KEY` or something in your question above.